# apache using lots of cpu

Tags: apache

I'm having a problem with apache (lamp). Once in a while i have a process that uses up one of my cpu's for like 5-20 secs.

Normally it would be php's fault, but after testing i could see that the php script finished. (at the final echo command) but just apache was waiting for something.  I have a blazing fast server with memory to spare, harddrives (300+Mb/s) almost doing nothing and less then 10% cpu utilization under high traffic.

below i have a dump from dstat, as you can see i have ~12 cpu usage for about 20 secs on the sys column, this happens when apache takes up one cpu.

```
usr sys idl wai hiq siq| read  writ| recv  send|  in   out | int   csw
  7  12  81   0   0   0|8192B    0 |  16k   96k|   0     0 |1302  3030 
  8  12  80   0   0   0|  16k    0 |  18k   99k|   0     0 |1297  2715 
 10  12  77   0   0   0| 248k 1384k|  24k  206k|   0     0 |1501  3857 
 15  12  73   0   0   0|  40k    0 |  36k  459k|   0     0 |1574  3643 
  9  12  79   1   0   0| 208k 4024k|  42k  427k|   0     0 |1865  3476 
  5  12  83   0   0   0|  56k  920k|  40k  574k|   0     0 |1648  2137 
  5  12  82   1   0   0| 160k    0 |  30k  275k|   0     0 |1556  2776 
  6  12  82   0   0   0|  96k 1776k|  23k  198k|   0     0 |1354  2811 
  3  12  85   0   0   0|  24k    0 |  18k  132k|   0     0 |1418  2200 
  5  12  83   0   0   0|  24k 3288k|  28k  263k|   0     0 |1457  2422 
  7  12  80   1   0   0| 176k 1080k|  29k  310k|   0     0 |1616  4206 
  5  12  83   1   0   0| 312k    0 |  63k  639k|   0     0 |1944  2776 
  4  12  73  10   0   0|  96k 8912k|  33k  366k|   0     0 |2652  2628 
  8  12  80   0   0   0|  56k    0 |  26k  232k|   0     0 |1401  2909 
  4  12  71  14   0   0|  88k    0 |  21k  178k|   0     0 |1492  3041 
  8  12  78   2   0   0| 144k 3984k|  61k  677k|   0     0 |1971  3893 
  5  12  83   0   0   0| 104k    0 |  35k  439k|   0     0 |1650  2878 
  5  12  81   1   0   0| 112k 1352k|  31k  210k|   0     0 |1476  3052 
  5  12  84   0   0   0|8192B 1792k|  15k  102k|   0     0 |1387  2663 
  4  13  81   2   0   0| 936k 4456k|  26k  162k|   0     0 |1491  2644 
  6  12  81   1   0   0| 200k 1336k|  33k  315k|   0     0 |1676  2829 
  7  15  77   1   0   0|  96k  672k|  37k  337k|   0     0 |1549  2758 
  9  13  77   1   0   0| 104k    0 |  51k  399k|   0     0 |1871  3614 
  5  12  82   0   0   0|  72k 2392k|  46k  427k|   0     0 |1685  2803 
  7  11  82   0   0   0|  64k    0 |  21k  214k|   0     0 |1487  2762 
  7   0  93   0   0   0|  32k    0 |  21k  155k|   0     0 |1310  2739 
  5   0  95   0   0   0|  32k    0 |  40k  333k|   0     0 |1675  2829
```

so how can i debug this? or what could it be?

Comment: something in apache log, maybe Ddos?

Comment: nothing in logs, no ddos going on, in this example we recieve between 32-60kb on the nic.

Comment: maybe gives us some more infos on the apache configuration, frequency of this event, mpm settings, ... Did you check all existing apache logs, especially the default error.log and access.log? Could maybe be another "internal dummy connections" problem. Ho, and maybe servfault gurus could be the best guys for you.

Comment: What distribution of your OS, and what apache version? Those can help narrow down what the issue might be.

Comment: i figured it out, it was the filesystem going nuts over the fact that i had 500K files in the session directory. go figure

Answer (score 0):

Are your machine have the mobile website?

In my experience, I have the same problem that is because of low bandwidth device connect to our mobile website which it is big. So, the apache have to hold the connection until the the client received all data and also send a acknowledge-signal back to the server that it can be close the connection.

You may try to 'netstat -pant' to see how many connections that apache currently wait for.